# Is Wolfram Alpha Wrong? (LU Decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, wolfram-alpha

Ok, I've been working on a matrix solver for a while (no, its not going well, thanks for asking), and just discovered something that worrys me alot;

The problem at hand is LU Decomposition of a square matrix, for example

$\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\
2&-1&1\\
3&4&-1\\
\end{matrix}$

WolframAlpha's [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LU%20decomposition%20%7B%7B1,2,3%7D,%7B2,-1,1%7D,%7B3,4,-1%7D%7D) is completely different from the example [source](http://www.hku.hk/cc/sp2/software/hpf/Course/HTMLQuestionsnode65.html)

Wolfram

$\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\
3&-2&-10\\
2&2.5&20\\
\end{matrix}$

Source

$\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\
2&-5&-5\\
3&0.4&-8\\
\end{matrix}$

What's going on?

Comment: I think your example source has some problem. Compare equation (3) with equation (6). $A$ is supposed to equal $LU$...

Comment: The Wolfram one also ends up being trying to take the LU decomposition of a row permutation of $A$. (It is the one for with the bottom two rows switched.)

Comment: @Willie: The example source is correct. Equation (6) you're referring to is showing how to store the $LU$ decomposition efficiently in one matrix.

Comment: @Theo: ah, thanks, I didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: Also, I think the question statement has a typo. Entry $(2,2)$ of the Wolfram compact representation should be $-2$ instead of $-1$.

Comment: FWIW, you might profit from having a look at [chapter 3 of Golub/Van Loan](http://books.google.com/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA87) while you're attempting to implement Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @JM already have it open on the desk! but thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like Wolfram Alpha is doing an LU decomposition with partial pivoting. So, it's actually solving a system like
$$\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\bm{P} \bm{A} = \bm{L} \bm{U}
$$
where $\bm{P}$ is a permutation matrix.

Curiously, it appears that Alpha simply isn't listing the permutation used in solving the system. In this case it is
$$
\bm{P} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right) .
$$

This is a common technique to enhance numerical stability.

You can recover $\bm{A}$ via
$$
\bm{A} = \bm{P}^{-1} \bm{L} \bm{U} = \bm{P L U}
$$
since in this case $\bm{P} = \bm{P}^{-1}$.

Comment: So both are correct but WA is swapping around A before decomposition?

Comment: I didn't check closely the other solution, but the Wolfram one is correct when the permutation is included.